# Iterate over array items and check property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
    function GetViewModelData() {
    var RDcViewModel = [];
    var recordId = $.trim($("#recordId").val());

    for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        var item1 = $.trim($("#item1" + i).val()) == '' ? 0 : parseInt($("#item1" + i).val());
        var item2 = $.trim($("#item2" + i).val()) == '' ? 0 : parseInt($("#item2" + i).val());
        var GrandTotal = (item1 + item2);
        var rdtCViewModel = new ItemDetailsViewModel(0, item1, item2, GrandTotal);
        RDcViewModel.push(rdtCViewModel);
    }

    var obj = new ReportViewModel(recordId, RDcViewModel);
    var viewmodel = JSON.stringify(obj);
    return viewmodel;
}
```

I have the above sample function that i'm using to iterate over html table rows and storing the row values in an array.

Once i have my array populated, i'm using below code snippet to post the data to my controller.

```
var PostData = function () {
$(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var viewmodel = GetViewModelData();
    //i want to check from here if viewmodel has any item(row) where GrandTotal is 0 (zero)
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: viewmodel,
        headers: GetRequestVerificationToken(),
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/' + virtualDirectory + '/Item/DataSave',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                window.location.href = '/' + virtualDirectory + '/Destination/Index';
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

}

What i now want to do in my PostData function is to check if my "viewmodel" object contains any item(row) where "GrandTotal" is 0.

Comment: check for 0 and then??

Comment: @Reddy and return false

Comment: ok, can you post what your `viewmodel` data is? i see its an object,

Comment: can you add the parsed json

Comment: if you could explain what is `recordId` here `var obj = new ReportViewModel(recordId, RDcViewModel);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `JSON.parse(viewmodel)`, prepare object of type `ReportViewModel` with `RDcViewModel` JS array of type `ItemDetailsViewModel` and iterate  over it to find if any grandtotal == 0 for `ItemDetailsViewModel` instances

```
  var viewmodel = GetViewModelData(),
  var obj = JSON.parse(viewmodel);
  var bFoundZero=false;
  $.each(obj.RDcViewModelArray, function(idx, elem){
     if( elem.GrandTotal === 0 ) bFoundZero=true;
  })
  if( bFoundZero ) return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have stringified it, now you have to parse it back if you want to access its keys and values:

```js
var PostData = function() {
  $(".btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var viewmodel = GetViewModelData(),
        viewObj = JSON.parse(viewmodel),
        flag = false; // <-----parse it back here

    viewObj.forEach(function(i, el){
        flag = el.GrandTotal === 0;
        return flag;
    });

    if(flag){ return false; }  // <------ and stop it here.


    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: viewmodel,
      headers: GetRequestVerificationToken(),
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/' + virtualDirectory + '/Item/DataSave',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == true) {
          window.location.href = '/' + virtualDirectory + '/Destination/Index';
        }
      },
      error: function(e) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point iterating array again. Break the loop in `GetViewModelData()` and return false from that function. Then test it in PostData

Inside existing for loop:

```
var GrandTotal = (item1 + item2);
if(!GrandTotal){
   return false; 
}
```

Then in PostData()

```
var PostData = function () {
$(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var viewmodel = GetViewModelData();
    if(viewmodel === false){
      alert('Missing total');
      return; //don't proceed
     }
     /* your ajax */
```

Comment: what if his existing function is being used else where? which might not require this changes

Comment: @Reddy OP can determine that.

Comment: in some places, its mandatory that GrandTotal can not be 0 while in others its optional(display only a warning). In some other places 0 is considered a valid value.

Comment: @charlietfl probably i didn't manage to explain it well, apologies if so but the answer by rt2800 is what i wanted.